# Mocha test fail ensure don() is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

Hi I have strange problem while testing code with Mocha:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Here is code:

```
describe('POST /notes', () => {
it('should create new note', (done) => {
    const title = 'Test title';
    const text = 'Test text';
    const category = 'Test category';
    request(app)
        .post('/notes')
        .send({title, text, category})
        .expect(200)
        .expect(res => {
            expect(res.body.title).toBe(title);
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            Note.find({text: text}).then(notes => {
                 expect(notes.length).toBe(1);
                 expect(notes[0].title).toBe(title);
                done();
            }).catch(err => done(err));
        });
});
it('should not create new note with invalid body data', done => {
    request(app)
        .post('/notes')
        .send({})
        .expect(400)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            Note.find().then(notes => {
                expect(notes.length).toBe(notesDummy.length);
                done();
            }).catch(err => done(err));
        });
})
```

});

First test fails with error described above. As it comes to the second, it passes. Both tests are similar and I don't know what I am missing... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interacting with a live database, it's possible that the operation just takes longer than 2 seconds to complete. The test for a successful operation would take longer than the negative test if you have server-side validation happening before interacting with the database.

You can extend the timeout in `mocha` using `this.timeout(<some number in milliseconds>)` :

```
it('should create new note', (done) => {
    this.timeout(9000); // set it to something big to see if it fixes your issue
    const title = 'Test title';
    const text = 'Test text';
    const category = 'Test category';
    request(app)
        .post('/notes')
        .send({title, text, category})
        .expect(200)
        .expect(res => {
            expect(res.body.title).toBe(title);
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            Note.find({text: text}).then(notes => {
                 expect(notes.length).toBe(1);
                 expect(notes[0].title).toBe(title);
                done();
            }).catch(err => done(err));
        });
});
```

The only other thing I can think of is that your server side code is hanging somewhere and not sending a response (or that `Notes.find()` is not resolving or rejecting for some reason). Your test code looks fine to me.

Comment: It looks like a bug... Mocha always fais first test for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that the `expect`s outside of promise-land at the beginning will cause `done` to be called if they fail:

```
    .expect(200)
    .expect(res => {
        expect(res.body.title).toBe(title);
    })
```

Maybe add some logging to see whether it ever gets to your `.end` handler?

Also, what are you importing to get `.expect` methods on your request? We should look at its docs to see about `done` hooks.